# vim-pressing arrow keys give 'after'

Tags: linux, vim

my vim is 7.0 and I can't update it to 7.3, i don't have the privilege.

How to produce the problem:
- in Vim, in any mode, if i keep pressing any arrow keys (either arrow keys or hjkl) it always gives this word "after". e.g:
`abcd efgh` gives `abcd efghafter`
very stupid.
I tried to put `set nocompatible` and

```
 map ^[[A <up>  
 map ^[[B <down>  
 map ^[[C <right>  
 map ^[[D <left>`
```

in vimrc, doesn't work...

Could you please help?

EDIT:

:map gives this:

```
v  <C-C>       * :call RangeCommentLine()<CR>  
no <C-C>       * :call CommentLine()<CR>  
n  <CR>        * :noh<CR><CR>  
n  <C-N>       * :<C-U>YRReplace '1', 'p'<CR>  
n  <C-P>       * :<C-U>YRReplace '-1', 'P'<CR>  
v  <C-X>       * :call RangeUnCommentLine()<CR>  
no <C-X>       * :call UnCommentLine()<CR>  
v  #           * :call VisualSearch('b')<CR>  
v  *           * :call VisualSearch('f')<CR>  
n  .           * :<C-U>YRYankCount '.'<CR>  
n  @             YRMapsExpression("<SNR>16_", "@", "1")  
n  D             D<SNR>16_yrrecord  
x  P           * :<C-U>YRPaste 'P', 'v'<CR>  
n  P           * :<C-U>YRPaste 'P'<CR>  
n  Y             Y<SNR>16_yrrecord  
x  d           * :YRDeleteRange 'v'<CR>  
n  dgg           dgg<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  dG            dG<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  d$            d$<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  daw           daw<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  diw           diw<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  dE            dE<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  de            de<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  dw            dw<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  dd            dd<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX  
n  gp          * :<C-U>YRPaste 'gp'<CR>  
n  gP          * :<C-U>YRPaste 'gP'<CR>  
v  jj            <Esc><Space>  
x  p           * :<C-U>YRPaste 'p', 'v'<CR>  
n  p           * :<C-U>YRPaste 'p'<CR>  
x  x           * :YRDeleteRange 'v'<CR>  
n  x             x<SNR>16_yrrecord  
x  y           * :YRYankRange 'v'<CR>  
n  ygg           ygg<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  yG            yG<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  y$            y$<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  yaw           yaw<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  yiw           yiw<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  yE            yE<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  ye            ye<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  yw            yw<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  yy            yy<SNR>16_yrrecord  
n  y           * "+y<Space>  
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>  
n  <SNR>16_yrrecord * :call YRRecord3()<CR>  
n  <F11>       * :YRShow<CR>
```

:imap gives

```
i  <S-Tab>     *@<C-R>=<SNR>13_SetVals()<CR><C-R>=<SNR>13_TabComplete('up')<CR><C-R>=<SNR>13_RestoreVals()<CR>
i  <Tab>       *@<C-R>=<SNR>13_SetVals()<CR><C-R>=<SNR>13_TabComplete('down')<CR><C-R>=<SNR>13_RestoreVals()<CR>
i  <SNR>16_yrrecord * <C-R>=YRRecord3()<CR>
i  <SNR>16_YRGetChar & <C-R>=YRGetChar()<CR>
i  jj            <Esc>
```

Comment: This is extremely odd behavior.  In Vim, do `:map` and see if it reveals any strange custom keybindings you've forgotten about.

Comment: Remove/rename the .vimrc and see if it still happens.

Comment: @CodyHess I just pasted the mapping in the question, please see EDIT.

Comment: @draevor i tried that but still doesn't work...

Comment: @CodyHess So, to better understand the problem: let's say you are in normal mode and you press `h` once - do you get the problem? how about if you press it repeatedly? or do you need to press various keys to get the word inserted? and does the word get inserted even if you're in normal mode?

Comment: @draevor if i press it once, it might not happen. It mostly happens when i'm at the end of the line and i keep pressing it. That's guaranteed to happen

Comment: @BPm - I use Vim 7.3 and I can't reproduce the problem.  Your `:map` doesn't give any obvious answers, and I can't imagine a situation where the errant addition of text is expected or acceptable behavior.  I would recommend bringing this up in the #vim irc channel (irc://irc.freenode.net/vim), though I imagine the best case scenario will be that you've identified an old bug and everyone will recommend that you upgrade to 7.3 (which you can't )= )

Comment: What's the output of `:imap`?  Insert mode mappings aren't shown in `:map`.

Comment: @RandyMorris please see the EDIT, i just included that :)

Comment: @CodyHess it sucks! it seems like i'm the only person who has this problem on google. i will try to work around and update my vim. THank you

Comment: May be it is an abbreviation? Try `:verbose abbreviate`

Comment: @Ves it gives 'no abbreviation found'

Comment: Maybe this page will help: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Debug_unexpected_option_settings

Comment: Try other places vimrc files are located such as /etc/vimrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to update to vim 7.3